# PHP cookie not being set

Tags: php, cookies

if I run this:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$expire = time()+(20*60);
$ssid = md5(rand()*1000000000);
setcookie('id', $ssid, $expire) or die("couldn't set cookie. login failed.");
```

It always dies. Any ideas why?

Comment: try without or die("couldn't set cookie. login failed.") and see what error you will get

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must set the cookie before doing anything else that produces output. Once the HTTP headers are sent, it's too late to set the cookie.

Comment: To expand: The only reason `setcookie()` would *ever* return false is if output has already been sent.

Answer (score 1):

The cookie headers should be set before anything. Remove the `die()` function and you should get a `headers already sent` error.